# What is the microscopic equation to calculate sound speed in an ideal gas?

Tags: acoustics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

The common equations to calculate the sound speed in an ideal gas use macroscopic quantities, e.g.:

$$c = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma RT}{M}}$$

What I am interested in is an equation that determines the sound speed in an ideal gas from a *microscopic* perspective. My reasoning is as follows: Sound propagates through an ideal gas by means of collisions between molecules. Since molecular movement is random, information that propagates from point A to point B via molecular collisions does not travel in a straight line but with an average angle of 45°.

The sound speed in an ideal gas should then be given by:

$$c = v_{rms} \space \sin{45°}$$
where $v_{rms}$ is the root-mean-square speed of molecules.

This equation gives results that are very close to the results given by the above formula (approx. 3% difference). Is my reasoning solid or what is a correct microscopic equation for sound speed in an ideal gas?

Comment: The speed of sound on a particle-by-particle basis does not make sense.  Sound is a collective phenomena inherently involving large numbers of particles, not individual particles.  So it really does not make sense to talk about sound and single particles unless you are comparing their individual speeds to that of sound.

Comment: @honeste_vivere: "The speed of sound in a gas will always be less than vrms since the sound propagates through the gas by disturbing the motion of the molecules.  The disturbance is passed on from molecule to molecule by means of collisions; a sound wave can therefore never travel faster than the average speed of the molecules." (http://teacher.pas.rochester.edu/phy121/lecturenotes/Chapter18/Chapter18.html). Since molecules move randomly, the disturbance/information does travel forward with an average angle of 45° between collisions.

Comment: You seem to be using the following logic:  if we pick a "forward direction" and randomly choose another vector with an angle between 0 and 90° relative to that forward vector, then on average their angle will be 45°, and so the average projection of the second vector on the "forward vector" will be $\cos 45° = \sin 45°$.  This is wrong for two reasons:  (1)  the cosine of the average angle is not the average of the cosines of all angles;  (2) gas particles move in three dimensions, not two, and in 3D it is more likely for the angle between two random vectors to be near 90° than it is near 0°.

Comment: If you calculate $\langle \cos \theta \rangle$ properly over all vectors that have a positive "forward" component, you get $2/\pi$ in 2D and $1/2$ in 3D.  Neither number is equal to $1/\sqrt{2}$, of course.

Comment: However the rms value of the component of velocity along a specific direction (for example the x component)  is vx=(1/sqrt(3)) vrms. Here vx is the rms value of the x component and vrms is the rms value of the velocity.